# How to limit the number of floating digits shown on confusion matrix plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I followed the example from this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py). When printing out the confusion matrix on console, it shows 2 floating digits (probably because of `np.set_printoptions(precision=2)`), but the output on the plot shows more than 2 digits.

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

# Compute confusion matrix
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names,
                      title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')

# Plot normalized confusion matrix
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=class_names, normalize=True,
                      title='Normalized confusion matrix')

plt.show()
```

The matrix output looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorten the text that you're plotting:

```
 plt.text(j, i, "{:0.2f}".format(cm[i, j]),
```